# Stop webserver on particular node using wsadmin (jython)

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

Is there any way to stop webserver on particular node using wsadmin?
Using

```
print AdminConfig.list('WebServer')
```

I got the list of all webservers with coresponding nodes

```
webserver1(cells/dmgrCell01/nodes/01Node01/servers/webserver1|server.xml#WebServer_0000000000)
webserver2(cells/dmgrCell01/nodes/01Node02/servers/webserver2|server.xml#WebServer_1111111111)
webserver3(cells/dmgrCell01/nodes/01Node03/servers/webserver3|server.xml#WebServer_2222222222)
```

According to IBM I need to define variable this way:

```
na = AdminControl.queryNames('type=NodeAgent,node=mynode,*')
```

so using type WebServer:

```
webserver = AdminControl.queryNames('type=WebServer,node=mynode,*')
```

but I got empty value

How to build this query?

Answer (score 1):

To stop a server you need to `invoke` the [stop command](https://lukesavefrogs.github.io/wsadmin-type-hints/cookbook/servers/#stop-server) passing the correct MBean.

If `AdminControl.queryNames(...)` returns an **empty string** it means that the MBean cannot be found using the `AdminControl` module (which manages *only* the running resources).

This could be caused by 2 major reasons:

- the target is already **stopped** (the MBean cannot be found using the AdminControl module (which manages *only* the running resources))
- the requested resource **does not exists** (and so it's not running)

### Stop running server

Try to build your query like this, then let me know:

```py
server = AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:cell=myCell,node=myNode,name=myServer,type=WebServer,*')

# Empty string ==> Server stopped
if server:
    AdminControl.invoke(server, 'stop')
```

### Stop from configuration ID

If you have the configuration ID of the resource, you can use the `AdminConfig.getObjectName(...)` to retrieve the running MBean corresponding to the resource configuration ID:

```py
# Get the configuration id from the configuration path
configuration_id = AdminConfig.getid("/Cell:myCell/WebServer:myServer/")

server = AdminConfig.getObjectName(configuration_id)

# Empty string ==> Server stopped
if server:
    AdminControl.invoke(server, 'stop')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have deployed the webserver1 on Node01, you can run the following query command at wsadmin command prompt and test it.

```py
webserver=AdminControl.queryNames("node="+AdminControl.getNode( )+",type=WebServer,*" )
```

once the above command executes, it will store the result into the variable `webserer`. To check the content of the variable you can simply use `webserver` and hit enter, that's it ! it will show you the MBean content.